# c++ class dynamically allocating an instance of itself

Tags: c++, class, memory

So I'm trying to figure out how to create a proper C++ class that can dynamically allocate and destroy itself. I came up with the following

```
class tClass {
public:
    tClass() {

        c = 0;
        extra = new int[1024 * 1024]; // To see memory usage

        while (true) {

            if (c != 1) {
                std::cout << "Name the class: ";
                std::cin >> str;
            }

            std::cout << "1 = create a new instance, 2 = delete this instance\n";
            std::cin >> c;

            if (c == 1) {
                tclass = new tClass();
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        }

        delete[] extra;
        this->~tClass();

    }

    ~tClass() {
        std::cout << "tClass " << str << " destroyed\n" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string str;
    tClass* tclass;
    int c;
    int* extra;
};

int main () {
    tClass *tclass = new tClass();
    delete tclass;
    return 0;
}
```

It works, but I'm sure it doesn't work in a healthy way. Is it really freeing all the memory it uses? Putting that "delete[] extra" into destructor eventually gives me memory access violation error.

Comment: The class should not manage itself. You can easily do what you want outside of the class. See [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: This is a very strange way to do things.

Comment: Why does the class constructor have to create and destroy the class? Why can't `main` create and destroy the class? Oh and the reason you got a memory access violation is probably because you deleted the first object twice.

Comment: `this->~tClass()` just leads to undefined behaviour. Why do you think you need this? You do `delete[] extra` in the constructor, doing it again in the destructor would be a double-free (though again, after that `this->~tClass()` all bets are off).

Comment: By the time you enter the constructor, the class has been already allocated either on stack or on the heap. There is no way you can do it yourself and there should be no need for it.

Comment: You're definitely leaking memory. Every `new` must be followed by a `delete`. You have 1 `delete` for N calls to `new`

Comment: A `class` instance simply cannot instantiate _itself_, it's paradoxical. However, it can instantiate other objects of its kind (`class`), or initiate its death by `delete this`.

Comment: Oh ho. C++ toxicity strikes again. Why the downvote?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. Thanks mr5 for giving me a hint.

```
class Slave {
public:
    Slave(const std::string& str): _str(str) {
        std::cout << "Slave " << _str << " was created\n";
    }

    ~Slave() {
        std::cout << "Slave " << _str << " was destroyed\n";
    }

private:
    std::string _str;
};

class Master {
public:
    Master() { 
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "1 = create new, 2 = delete latest\n";
            std::cin >> c;

            if (c == 1)
                Create();
            else
                if (!Destroy())
                    break;
        }
    }

    ~Master() {}

    void Create() {
        std::cout << "Name the new class: ";
        std::cin >> str;
        slaves.push_back(new Slave(str));
    }

    bool Destroy() {
        if (slaves.size() > 0) {
            delete slaves[slaves.size() - 1];
            slaves.pop_back();
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

private:
    std::string str;
    std::vector<Slave*> slaves;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    Master* master = new Master();
    delete master;
    return 0;
}
```